# matplotlib issue with plotting lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, line

I am having a strange issue with plotting lists using matplotlib. The code is below.

```
plt.plot([timeList],[zeroList], linestyle="--", color="red", marker="o")
plt.plot([10,20,30],[14,25,34], linestyle="--", color="red", marker="o")
```

This is what I get, why is the first plot not displaying a dashed line?

[image]

---

Removing the [] on the lists works fine, thanks.

Comment: What does ``timeList`` and ``zeroList`` contain? Are they already lists, if so try to remove the outer list brackets.

Comment: They contain 7 values each, I will try that, Thanks.